# MEV bot on Github - does it look like a scam?

Tags: scam, mev, bot, audit

this one was recently added to Github, my first opinion is that it is probably a scam. Can anyone take a look and let me know if anything fishy is in the smart contract code? If so then I will report them so it can be taken down.

https://github.com/zrula/MEV-BOT